# ES6 block-scope variable usage

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I am experimenting with ES6 using BabelJS in a codepen project you can find [here](http://codepen.io/agraptor/pen/dGVrEY?editors=1010). I am confused as to why my code breaks when I decide to use `let` instead of `var` in the following function:

```
function getUnits(country) {
const imperialCountries = ['US', 'BS', 'BZ', 'KY', 'PW'];

if (imperialCountries.indexOf(country) === -1) {
  var units = 'metric';
} else {
  units = 'imperial';
}
console.log(country, units);
return units;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's all about [scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/1014587).

Comment: [Questions seeking help about debugging or understanding code are off-topic for Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, `let` variable bindings are local to the scope. In your example you have two scopes inside the `getUnits` function:

```
function getUnits(country) {
  // function scope
  if (imperialCountries.indexOf(country) === -1) {
    // scope 1
  } else {
    // scope 2
  }
}
```

If you declare a variable using the `let` keyword in either of the inner scopes, it **will be unbound** once that scope finishes.

When you declare variables with the `var` keyword they will still be bound outside of the inner scopes of the given function. Effectively, using `var` as in your example, is the same as this:

```
function getUnits(country) {
  var units;

  if (imperialCountries.indexOf(country) === -1) {
    units = 'metric';
  } else {
    units = 'imperial';
  }
}
```

If you wish to use `let` then just replace the `var` in the above example with it.

One more thing, since the `imperialCountries` variable is a `const`, it might be better to keep it outside of the `getUnits` function. (Unless you do not wish to pollute the global namespace)

Answer (score 2):

`let` and `const` allows us to declare block scoped variable. In your code

```
if (imperialCountries.indexOf(country) === -1) {
  var units = 'metric';
} else {
  units = 'imperial';
}
```

when you replace `var` with `let` the variable units becomes a block scoped variable and is recognized only inside the `if` block. You can make the following change in your code to use `let`:

```
let units;
if (imperialCountries.indexOf(country) === -1) {
  units = 'metric';
} else {
  units = 'imperial';
}
```